# extract thumbnail from online video link

Tags: python, memory, video, thumbnails

I am building a website, and I am trying to extract one image from a video directly using the link provide by a user.

The things is that all need to be done in memory: download the video in memory (using requests for example), extract an image and I upload it on my aws bucket

I have searched for a solution and found cv2. I was able locally to extract one image using:

```
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_vid)
res, thumb_buf = cv2.imencode('.png', im_ar)
bt = thumb_buf.tostring()
```

The issue is, after some research, reading and decoding from bytes or content of response is not supported, so I am back to the beginning.

Ideally I wanted something like this:

```
r = requests.get(url)
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(io.BytesIO(r.content))
res, thumb_buf = cv2.imencode('.png', im_ar)
bt = thumb_buf.tostring()
```

Comment: What's the problem with the second code example?

Comment: What are the first 4 characters in `bt` if it is a String object? Is it `2550` or is is `%PNG`? You need to have a **hex** String (is `2550`) and not as **UTF** text (is `%PNG`). File bytes are written in hex format. Maybe try as `bt = thumb_buf.tostring(16)`.